# Sample uniformly from multisets

Tags: python, math, numpy

Given the set of integers {1,...,n}, I would like to sample uniformly from the binom{n+k-1}{k} distinct multi-subsets of size k.   Is there an efficient way of doing this?

For example, the set {1,2,3} has  6 multi-subsets of size 2. These are {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3}.

Comment: Could you please give me an example case? I'm not the best when it comes to mathematical notation or vocab, but if you can give me the gist of what you're trying to achieve, perhaps I can be of help.

Comment: You mean partitions of {1, ..., n}?

Comment: See the multiset coefficients from http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset . That page also has lots of examples.

Comment: Posted an answer that shouldn't be misleading garbage this time. I've *solved* this problem before; I should have remembered multinomial coefficients were the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Since you know there are (n+k-1) choose k such multi-subsets, you are probably aware of the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) combinatorial problem whose solution provides that formula. The solution to that problem suggests a sampling procedure to produce multi-subsets: randomly choose a way to place k stars and n-1 bars, then determine how the bars partition the stars into groups:

```
import random
import collections

stars = set(random.sample(xrange(n+k-1), k))
multiset = collections.Counter()

# Don't hide the bin builtin.
bin_ = 1
for i in xrange(n+k-1):
    if i in stars:
        multiset[bin_] += 1
    else:
        bin_ += 1
```

This will produce a `collections.Counter` counting the number of times each number was chosen. I've initialized `bin_ = 1` to produce a multi-subset of {1...n}; `bin_ = 0` would produce a multi-subset of {0...n-1}.

(Previously, I posted an answer suggesting the use of a multinomial distribution. That is *not* the right distribution; it gives too little weight to results with repeated elements. Sorry for the error. Since the ways to place k stars and n-1 bars are in direct correspondence with the multi-subsets of {1...n}, this solution should produce a uniform distribution.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot test my solution now, it is based on the pervious one:

```
import random as rd
#n,k - should be predefined
x=[[j]*k for j in xrange(n)] # [1,1,1,1 - k times, 2,2,2,- k times etc.]
rd.sample(x,k)
```